# Identical .so shared libraries (with no symbols) are generated when compiling different C source files

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, gnu-make

At the institution I work for we have a User Exit made in Pro*C (SQL embedded in C language). We are having some troubles because identical shared libraries are generated when compiling different source files. These .so files have no symbols. Everything was working alright just a few days ago, but suddenly this trouble occurred. What can we do?

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libentorno.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libconexion.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name 27440 Dec 23 11:27 libmsg.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libgralib.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name 88968 Dec 23 11:27 libeval.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name   7680 Dec 23 11:27 libifcp0160.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libifcp0150.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name   7680 Dec 23 11:27 libobn_calculo.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libdvo.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name   7680 Dec 23 11:27 libobn.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name  7680 Dec 23 11:27 libmasiva.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user_name user_name 2404472 Dec 23 11:28 libtax.so
```

We also cannot compile separate binary executables:

```
$ make -f ~/build/tax.mk ejecutable EXE=pmca0010
Procesando .pc -> .c
/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/bin/proc sqlcheck=semantics dbms=v8 userid=tax/manejoint@taxd release_cursor=no hold_cursor=yes maxopencursors=100 include=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/rdbms/public include=/home/user_name/user_exit/src/inc iname=/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Dec 23 11:29:26 2021
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Procesando .c -> .o
gcc -c -fPIC -g  -I/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64/ -I/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/rdbms/public -I/home/user_name/user_exit/src/inc  -o /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c
Generando pmca0010...
gcc -L/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib/ -L/home/user_name/user_exit/lib -lifcp0150 -lmsg -lifcp0160 -lobn -lgralib -ldvo -leval -lobn_calculo -lmasiva -lconexion -lclntsh -lcrypt -lrt \
      -o /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010 /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libentorno.so, needed by /home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libconexion.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `main':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3942: undefined reference to `error_func'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3944: undefined reference to `ParametrosOracle'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3970: undefined reference to `f_utl_file'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3974: undefined reference to `SetArchivoErr'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3975: undefined reference to `SetArchivoLog'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3976: undefined reference to `SetArchivoDebug'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3981: undefined reference to `g_archivo_trace_uex'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3987: undefined reference to `g_archivo_trace_uex'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:3995: undefined reference to `f_debug'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4044: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4046: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4047: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4070: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4138: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4164: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4177: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4178: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4179: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4180: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4181: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o:/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4182: more undefined references to `DebugAArchivo' follow
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `main':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4240: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4246: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4287: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4293: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4341: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4347: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4365: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4370: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `get_usuario':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4390: undefined reference to `LeerVariableEntorno'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4399: undefined reference to `LeerVariableEntorno'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `obn_generar_masiva_paralelo':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4549: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4550: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4551: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4561: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4663: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4664: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4669: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4683: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4684: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4685: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4686: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o:/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4688: more undefined references to `DebugAArchivo' follow
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `obn_generar_masiva_paralelo':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4771: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4772: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4780: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4781: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4903: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:4919: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5138: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5148: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5252: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5267: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5270: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5372: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5379: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5382: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5391: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5451: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5463: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5464: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5493: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5562: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5578: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5580: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5680: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5687: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5694: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5698: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5699: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5710: undefined reference to `RecuperarCreditoMasiva'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5716: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5723: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5729: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5746: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5757: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5758: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5759: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5760: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5762: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5763: undefined reference to `obn_srv_obligacion_masiva'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5788: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5789: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5790: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5798: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5816: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5824: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5826: undefined reference to `grabar_error_masiva_objetos'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5828: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5829: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5839: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5840: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5848: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5866: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5874: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5876: undefined reference to `grabar_error_masiva_objetos'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5878: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5879: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5889: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5892: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5893: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o:/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5904: more undefined references to `DebugAArchivo' follow
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o: In function `obn_generar_masiva_paralelo':
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5923: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5932: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5934: undefined reference to `grabar_error_masiva_objetos'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5936: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5950: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5969: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5978: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5979: undefined reference to `grabar_error_masiva_objetos'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5980: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:5994: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6038: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6049: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6070: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6085: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6142: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6147: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6154: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6208: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6284: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6289: undefined reference to `DebugAArchivo'
/home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c:6313: undefined reference to `LogError'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_PROPORCIONAL_BAJA'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2020B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_MONTO_EX'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2014'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AMAX_ADIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2001'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AMIN_ADIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2016B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_DEVENGADO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_APLICA_TOPE'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_CUOTA'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_PORCENTAJE_EX'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `PLAN_PAGO_CALCULAR'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2015'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2002'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_FIJO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `CALCULAR_ADICIONAL'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_ALICUOTA'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2018B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2019B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AMIN_ALIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2016'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_TRATAMIENTO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_VARIACION_PORCENTUAL'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_AUTOMOTOR_1999'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2017'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `INTERES_RESARCITORIO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2021B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2018'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_INTERES_SI_NO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AVMIN_ALIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2013B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AVMAX_ALIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_DIF_CENSO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AMAX_ALIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_IMPORTE_EX'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2017B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2019'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_FACTURADO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_AVALUO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2015B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2006'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_PROPORCIONAL'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_TIPO_SUJETO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AVMIN_ADIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_CANT_MULTAS'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2020'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AVMAX_ADIC'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_TIPO_EX'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_IMPUESTO_MIN'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2021'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `GET_CREDITO'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `SET_IME_AMAX_ALIC_RUR'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2014B'
/home/user_name/user_exit/lib/libeval.so: undefined reference to `IMPUESTO_INMUEBLE_2013'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ejecutable] Error 1
rm /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.c
```

The libraries produced by the compiler do not have symbols:

```
$ nm libgralib.so
0000000000201028 B __bss_start
0000000000201028 b completed.6355
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000540 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000005b0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200dd0 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000200de0 d __dso_handle
0000000000200de8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000201028 D _edata
0000000000201030 B _end
0000000000000628 T _fini
00000000000005f0 t frame_dummy
0000000000200dc8 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000638 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000004f0 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000200dd8 d __JCR_END__
0000000000200dd8 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000570 t register_tm_clones
0000000000201028 d __TMC_END__
```

Thank you

PS: Some of the files generated are **EXACTLY** the same:

```
$ md5sum *.so | sort
3f3a8fba409013b23ff52a25ef1a292d  libifcp0150.so
440c761aac25771468e384e71977a50c  libentorno.so
440c761aac25771468e384e71977a50c  libifcp0160.so
52b79262a71da8ed1559ce8f644f512d  libobn.so
70be43604caa02b188e8f703e6edcf7e  libdvo.so
70be43604caa02b188e8f703e6edcf7e  libobn_calculo.so
8bfc42eb45a0cfd5cf8a5e62b73e99b2  libmasiva.so
9b4c31fe428a62af7d3334938a594977  libconexion.so
b3916ef1db33449a21a06c7f2d4f05cc  libgralib.so
ce825bb91af0ea64d50e34fcd3188d43  libmsg.so
d8e31590af6725a7a866f671b9e13aaa  libeval.so
e2780910964cf8287346e9f2495aff89  libtax.so
```

Also, when I try to compile a binary:

```
$ make -f ~/build/tax.mk ejecutable EXE=pmca0010
Procesando .pc -> .c
/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/bin/proc sqlcheck=semantics dbms=v8 userid=tax/manejoint release_cursor=no hold_cursor=yes maxopencursors=100 include=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/rdbms/public include=../src/inc iname=../src/pc/pmca0010.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Dec 27 12:00:16 2021
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Procesando .c -> .o
gcc -c -fPIC -g  -I/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64/ -I/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/rdbms/public -I../src/inc  -o ../src/pc/pmca0010.o ../src/pc/pmca0010.c
Generando pmca0010...
gcc -L/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib/ -L../lib -lifcp0150 -lmsg -lifcp0160 -lobn -lgralib -ldvo -leval -lobn_calculo -lmasiva -lconexion -lclntsh -lcrypt -lrt \
    -o ../src/pc/pmca0010 ../src/pc/pmca0010.o
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/pc/pmca0010.o: undefined reference to symbol 'LeerVariableEntorno'
/app/tax/lib/libentorno.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ejecutable] Error 1
rm ../src/pc/pmca0010.c
```

Answer (score 0):

> Everything was working alright just a few days ago, but suddenly this trouble occurred.

A guess: you've modified your `~/build/tax.mk` makefile (or something it includes).

> What can we do?

Use appropriate revision control system, so you know what's changed, why and when.

This command line:

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib/ -L/home/user_name/user_exit/lib \
  -lifcp0150 -lmsg -lifcp0160 -lobn -lgralib -ldvo -leval -lobn_calculo \
  -lmasiva -lconexion -lclntsh -lcrypt -lrt \
  -o /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010 \
  /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o
```

is *wrong*. It should be:

```
gcc /home/user_name/user_exit/src/pc/pmca0010.o \
  -L/... -L/...  -lifcp0150 -lmsg -lifcp0160 ... \
```

To understand why libraries should *follow* object files on the command line, read [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180627210132/http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).